# Making awk remainder operator work like Python's

Tags: awk

In python, I can do the following:

```
 >>> -1 % 5 
 4
```

Awk's remainder operator returns `-1` instead. Is there a quick and easy way to get `4` instead of `-1` on awk?

**Edit:** I want to be able to fold any number into the `0-4` range. For instance, `-6 % 5 = 4`. I also need this to work with floats as well: `-1.5 % 5.1 = 3.6`.

Comment: Is adding 5 to negative outcomes quick and easy?

Comment: @lenz The problem is, I might have `-6` or even smaller numbers.

Comment: Oh I see, `-6 % 5` gives you `-6`... Then you have multiply the input with `-1` and subtract the output from 5 (unless it is 0). Doesn't look quick and easy anymore...

Comment: but then adding 5 to -1 gives you 4, doesn't it?

Comment: @lenz : `" -6 % 5 gives you -6"` …… what ??

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto looks like a mistake. I can't _quite_ remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the modulo this way to get same behaviour:

```
awk '{ print ((-1%5)+5)%5 }'
```

which should work even if the number is negative (`5` here).

awk's modulo is probably acts as remainder operator (just like in C) as opposed to mathematical modulo done by Python.

Comment: That's the brute force way to do it, but it requires 2 relatively expensive modulo `%` operations and an addition, unconditionally.  It certainly works.  It is tempting to do `x = -1%5; if (x < 0) x = (x + 5) % 5;` instead.  I've not tested whether the condition is more expensive in a pipelined CPU than the extra computation.

Comment: Since when is the modulo operator expensive, @JonathanLeffler?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod: Cost is relative, but 'since the beginning of computation', relative to the cost of addition, or even multiplication.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I was misremembering how long the div instruction takes.

Answer (score 2):

I would think an inline "if" like this might be the way to go:

```
$ awk -v n=-6 -v m=5 'BEGIN{ print (n>=0) ? n%m : m+(n%m); }'
4
```

Or if you like,

```
function pymod(n,m) {
  return (n>=0) ? n%m : m+(n%m);
}
```

Saves you from doing an extra modulo.  Note that the final parentheses are unnecessary thanks to order of operations; I include them only for clarity.

Disclaimer: I am not a mathematician, nor do I play one on TV.